# Can I import an existing member data used in old ASP to a new ASP.NET membership database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I have an old website that I designed and still maintain using old ASP that has a membership database (SQL Server) that I built from scratch. It is a very simple database that has all the user information in one table (including login info and personal info) and then details and other odds and ends in other tables.

It is WAY past time to upgrade this to .NET, especially since I need to add a Paypal payment system into it as soon as I can. I've designed several other sites with membership in .NET, but they have all been from scratch. Is there an easy way to transition from the old ASP site to a new .NET membership database without losing the data?  There are hundreds of users with thousands of records relating to those users that I'd rather not lose, if possible.

Any ideas on a relatively painless way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a pain, to be sure. I guess I would start by writing views on the existing tables that would have the same columns and data types as the target tables (aspnet_Users, aspnet_membership, etc.). Stuff that doesn't fall into that structure will probably need to wind up in the profile table OR continue to exist in a secondary table(s) with a FK out to the aspnet_Users table. I'm not a big fan of the Profile system.

Unless you just lucked out, and the old system also uses a GUID as the PK, that will probably be the real pain - getting all of your other FK's converted. You probably won't get too deep into the problem before it becomes very difficult to do it in pure SQL, so I would resign myself to writing maybe a lightweight console app that uses the native Membership stuff.

Good luck, and HTH.

Comment: This post has some code to carry out Chris' latter point
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506805/import-users-to-asp-net-membership-from-a-file

Comment: The old system does not use a GUID, just a plain old auto-incremented integer. :(