# Importing users from database table to ASPNET membership table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am building a web application that uses asp.net membership tables:

[image]

The application interacts with data imported from a third party application. This application has it's own user table:

[image]

Looking at the aspnet memebership tables, it appears there are many generated keys and values. SO I can't directly import the usernames an emails to it.

Is it possible to import the users to the tables so I don't have to put them all in manually?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Write a sql script to insert the data from your target table into the membership tables

Comment: It will auto generate all of the keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506805/import-users-to-asp-net-membership-from-a-file